# Error when deploying changeset Home Page Default Lightning Page

Tags: lightning, deployment, change-set

The error message received when deploying Home Page Default Lightning Page :

```
Invalid property [hideSearchBar] in component [flexipage:filterListCard]
```

[image: Deployment error msg]

Source environment uses Winter 19 edition.
Target environment uses Summer 18 Edition.

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot push metadata from a preview sandbox to an environment on an older version if it contains metadata structures introduced in the new version. The metadata "hideSearchBar" appears to refer to the new feature in Winter '19  where a user can search within a list view [Find the Data You Need in a Jiffy with List View Search](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_lex_search_lists.htm).

In order to deploy, you'll need to remove the `<componentInstanceProperties>` element which contains `hideSearchBar` from your metadata. Once your target instance is upgraded you can re-add the property if you need to hide the search bar.